# Azure DevOps Databricks Pipeline Release exits with [error]Bash exited with code '1'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-databricks

My Azure Devops pipeline fails withn [error]Bash exited with code '1'.

The script is a follows:

```
databricks workspace mkdirs /build
databricks workspace import --language PYTHON --format SOURCE --overwrite _databricks-example-repo/notebook/$(notebook_name)-$(Build.SourceVersion).py /build/$(notebook_name)-$(Build.SourceVersion).py
```

The full error message is a follows:

```
2019-10-16T10:41:42.2582015Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2019-10-16T10:41:42.2583038Z [command]"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --noprofile --norc /d/a/_temp/89026089-f163-495a-92ea-285e19705127.sh
2019-10-16T10:41:42.7609581Z Error: InvalidConfigurationError: You haven't configured the CLI yet! Please configure by entering `C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.7.4\x64\Scripts\databricks configure`
2019-10-16T10:41:43.1620919Z Error: InvalidConfigurationError: You haven't configured the CLI yet! Please configure by entering `C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.7.4\x64\Scripts\databricks configure`
2019-10-16T10:41:43.1991465Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
2019-10-16T10:41:43.2007318Z ##[section]Finishing: Upload Notebook
```

Any thoughts

Comment: Did you start by following the instructions provided by the error message?

Comment: @DanielMann, if you mean 'Configuring the CLI', I attempted to follow the instructions in the Databricks documentation https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-cli.html however, when I enter the command ```%sh
databricks configure --token```  the command just continues running and I'm never presented with the output ```Databricks Host (should begin with https://):
Token:```  Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: just so you know, I have been following the guide here https://medium.com/@bedatse/azure-devops-ci-cd-with-azure-databricks-and-data-factory-part-1-c05a44536a8e

Comment: So, I started the whole exercise again, and I think I know why I was getting the error. I believe its because of the previous error, which is  ```2019-10-16T16:20:27.1101608Z /home/vsts/work/_temp/adc19048-9436-42aa-b065-9a286f8a5496.sh: line 3: databricks-token: command not found
2019-10-16T16:20:27.3950190Z Databricks Host (should begin with https://): Token: Token: Aborted!
2019-10-16T16:20:27.4278386Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.``` Any thoughts?

Comment: I think I may have figured out the why I have been getting the above issue. I believe its because when I issue the command databricks configure --token in Databricks notebook I should get the following output ```Databricks Host (should begin with https://):
Token:``` However, the command just keeps on running as if it's waiting for me to enter additional commands. Can you let me know when command doesn't issue the command prompts as described on Databricks official site https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-cli.html  ?

Comment: I know that someone is likely ask if I have created a token? The answer is yes, I have created a token, but each time I enter the command ```databricks configure --token 
Host = https://uksouth.azuredatabricks.net
token = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx``` I keep on getting the message Databricks Host (should begin with https://): Token: Token: Aborted

Comment: ok, I have done some more reading around this issue. 1st thing is I should be running the command ```databricks configure --token``` on either a PC or a Unix box, not from a Databricks notebook. 2nd, after issuing the command I should get the prompt asking me to enter hostname/auth-token at prompt. However, when I issue the command I get the following response from Unix box "Waiting for console output from an agent...". I am running Python 3. So can someone please let me know if the command is compatible with Python 3? And why I'm not getting the prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been trying to solve this for past two days. I finally realised that the problem was that I entered the wrong token ID. My advice is take nothing for granted when configuring systems .. I was 100% sure the token ID wasn't the issue, but when re-entered the token ID correctly it worked. I'm so upset with myself. 
Thanks for your contributions anyway

Answer (score 0):

For me, the token ID was not the problem. I had to add the databricks host and token as environment variables to the bash task. Having at as global variable did not suffice. So in the bash task, I unfolded "Environment variables" and added:

Name;            Value

DATABRICKS_HOST;  $(DATABRICKS_HOST)

DATABRICKS_TOKEN; $(DATABRICKS_TOKEN)

This solved the issue